# Json msg NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: api, flutter

```
class Associado {
  final int codigo;
  final String nome;
  final String email;
  final String telefone;
  final String apelido;
  final String cnh;
  final String cpf;
  final String rg;
  final String tipoSanguineo;
  final String dataNascimento;
  final String dataEscudamento;
  final Dependente dependente;

  Associado(
      this.codigo,
      this.nome,
      this.email,
      this.telefone,
      this.apelido,
      this.cnh,
      this.cpf,
      this.rg,
      this.tipoSanguineo,
      this.dataNascimento,
      this.dataEscudamento,
      this.dependente);

  Associado.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : codigo = json['codigo'],
        nome = json['nome'],
        email = json['email'],
        telefone = json['telefone'],
        apelido = json['apelido'],
        cnh = json['cnh'],
        cpf = json['cpf'],
        rg = json['rg'],
        tipoSanguineo = json['tipoSanguineo'],
        dataNascimento = json['dataNascimento'],
        dataEscudamento = json['dataEscudamento'],
        dependente = Dependente.fromJson(json['dependente']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'codigo': codigo,
        'nome': nome,
        'email': email,
        'telefone': telefone,
        'apelido': apelido,
        'cnh': cnh,
        'cpf': cpf,
        'rg': rg,
        'tipoSanguineo': tipoSanguineo,
        'dataNascimento': dataNascimento,
        'dataEscudamento': dataEscudamento,
        'dependente': dependente.toJson(),
      };

}

class Dependente {
  final int codigo;
  final String nome;
  final String email;
  final String telefone;
  final String tipoSanguineo;
  final String dataNascimento;
  final String membroHC;

  Dependente(this.codigo, this.nome, this.email, this.telefone,
      this.tipoSanguineo, this.dataNascimento, this.membroHC);

  Dependente.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : codigo = json['codigo'],
        nome = json['nome'],
        email = json['email'],
        telefone = json['telefone'],
        tipoSanguineo = json['tipoSanguineo'],
        dataNascimento = json['dataNascimento'],
        membroHC = json['membroHC'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'codigo': codigo,
        'nome': nome,
        'email': email,
        'telefone': telefone,
        'tipoSanguineo': tipoSanguineo,
        'dataNascimento': dataNascimento,
        'membroHC': membroHC,
      };


}
```

When I call the method below

```
  Future<List<Associado>> findByCodigo(int codigo) async {
    final Response response =
    await client.get(baseUrl + codigo.toString()).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
    final List<dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return decodedJson
        .map((dynamic json) => Associado.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  }
```

I got the json correctly

```
I/flutter ( 7081): body: [{"codigo":1,"version":0,"nome":"Adalberto Jr","email":"atajr.650@gmail.com","telefone":"992107728","apelido":"Pantera Negra","cnh":"000000000","cpf":"71701265320","rg":"224643940","tipoSanguineo":"A-","dataNascimento":"1976-09-28T03:00:00.000+00:00","dataEscudamento":"2019-07-17T03:00:00.000+00:00","dependentes":[{"codigo":1,"version":0,"nome":"Giovanna Liz","email":"gioliz@hotmail.com","telefone":"992107728","tipoSanguineo":"AB+","dataNascimento":"2020-09-11T03:00:00.000+00:00","membroHc":null,"novo":true},{"codigo":2,"version":0,"nome":"Cailini Lima","email":"cailinilima@gmail.com","telefone":"988513328","tipoSanguineo":"A+","dataNascimento":"1993-01-23T03:00:00.000+00:00","membroHc":null,"novo":true}],"novo":true}]
```

But after, I got the msg below:

```
E/flutter ( 7081): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 7081): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7081): Tried calling: []("codigo")
```

Here's all the run log:

```
I/flutter ( 7081): Response
I/flutter ( 7081): status code: 200
I/flutter ( 7081): body: [{"codigo":1,"version":0,"nome":"Adalberto Jr","email":"atajr.650@gmail.com","telefone":"992107728","apelido":"Pantera Negra","cnh":"000000000","cpf":"71701265320","rg":"224643940","tipoSanguineo":"A-","dataNascimento":"1976-09-28T03:00:00.000+00:00","dataEscudamento":"2019-07-17T03:00:00.000+00:00","dependentes":[{"codigo":1,"version":0,"nome":"Giovanna Liz","email":"gioliz@hotmail.com","telefone":"992107728","tipoSanguineo":"AB+","dataNascimento":"2020-09-11T03:00:00.000+00:00","membroHc":null,"novo":true},{"codigo":2,"version":0,"nome":"Cailini Lima","email":"cailinilima@gmail.com","telefone":"988513328","tipoSanguineo":"A+","dataNascimento":"1993-01-23T03:00:00.000+00:00","membroHc":null,"novo":true}],"novo":true}]
I/flutter ( 7081): headers: {content-type: application/json, date: Tue, 23 Jun 2020 20:19:24 GMT, transfer-encoding: chunked}
E/flutter ( 7081): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(199)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7081): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 7081): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7081): Tried calling: []("codigo")
E/flutter ( 7081): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter ( 7081): #1      new Dependente.fromJson (package:hcslzapp/models/dependente.dart:14:22)
E/flutter ( 7081): #2      new Associado.fromJson (package:hcslzapp/models/associado.dart:43:33)
E/flutter ( 7081): #3      AssociadoWebClient.findByCodigo.<anonymous closure> (package:hcslzapp/http/webclients/associado_webclient.dart:24:42)
E/flutter ( 7081): #4      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:417:29)
E/flutter ( 7081): #5      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:221:19)
E/flutter ( 7081): #6      AssociadoWebClient.findByCodigo (package:hcslzapp/http/webclients/associado_webclient.dart:25:10)
E/flutter ( 7081): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7081): #7      HCSlzApp.build (package:hcslzapp/main.dart:35:16)
E/flutter ( 7081): #8      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4291:28)
E/flutter ( 7081): #9      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15)
E/flutter ( 7081): #10     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
E/flutter ( 7081): #11     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2432:33)
E/flutter ( 7081): #12     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:773:20)
E/flutter ( 7081): #13     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
E/flutter ( 7081): #14     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
E/flutter ( 7081): #15     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
E/flutter ( 7081): #16     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:850:7)
E/flutter ( 7081): #17     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter ( 7081): #18     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
E/flutter ( 7081): #19     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
E/flutter ( 7081): #20     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
```

Any idea??

Tks

Comment: where is the `print` that logged the json body?

Comment: Did you use https://quicktype.io/ to make your modal class.

Comment: Python Hub, good idea. I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
dependente = Dependente.fromJson(json['dependente']
```

property `dependente` does not exist on your json. You have a property `dependentes` that is a list

```
"dependentes": [
{
  "codigo": 1,
  "version": 0,
  "nome": "Giovanna Liz",
  "email": "gioliz@hotmail.com",
  "telefone": "992107728",
  "tipoSanguineo": "AB+",
  "dataNascimento": "2020-09-11T03:00:00.000+00:00",
  "membroHc": null,
  "novo": true
},
{
  "codigo": 2,
  "version": 0,
  "nome": "Cailini Lima",
  "email": "cailinilima@gmail.com",
  "telefone": "988513328",
  "tipoSanguineo": "A+",
  "dataNascimento": "1993-01-23T03:00:00.000+00:00",
  "membroHc": null,
  "novo": true
}]
```

Declare `dependentes` like this

```
final List<Dependente> dependentes;
```

and then build it from json using this code

```
dependente = List.from((json['incidentCategoryResponses'] as List)
                    .map((dependente) => Dependente.fromJson(dependente)))
```

Comment: Claudio, I'm trying to convert dependente to a List<Dependentes> but I don't know how to do it.